# pipe as well as socket connection on AWS lambda failed in _get_remote_context pyuno

Tags: sockets, aws-lambda, pipe, libreoffice

I am tying to use LibreOffice using custom runtime environment as ECR image on AWS Lambda. This whole setup works in Windows as well as on Linux, as soon as I pushing to Lambda using ECR image, the lambda fails to open Pipe or socket to communicate with LibreOffice. The same image works well on my linux system.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of research, I came to the solution and now I am able to Copy an excel sheet with (data + formula + formatting) to another workbook, thanks to
`subprocess.Open`'s `Shell` and `CWD` arguments.